# Solution for relative position of nodes in Sprite kit scene editor?

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

I am just a beginner in game developing. Right now I am developing a game using Apple's Sprite kit and found out that the best way to position nodes on the scene is to provide percentages of width and height of the window boundaries as it makes sure all the nodes maintain their positions almost regardless of change in device display size. Using pixels to position nodes is not a peculiar idea as with the change in device display size of iPhone, nodes are either cut off or the scene squeezes leaving empty space around the scene boundary. I have watched how Apple recommend using scene editor but my issue is, using scene editor it allows you to position nodes by choosing pixels and not relative to to scene width or height. Am I making a mistake in understanding the scene editor capability. If I position all my nodes using scene editor as its saves a lot of time, how can I avoid problem with different iPhone sizes. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Using a percentage is actually the worst possible way.  You are doing way too much division and you are leaving yourself to make mistakes

Answer (score 1):

This is an age old problem, from all media formats.

You must decide, personally, what your favourite and most desirable target device is, and then make choices best for both it, and your creative process.

After making that decision you'll have to make your own decisions on how compromised you become on other devices, or how much you compromise your creative and production processes to benefit other device sizes and aspect ratios.

It's a balancing act.

And I strongly suggest favouring your favourite device and putting off all consideration of adaptation to other devices until after you've made something great.

Others will disagree.

Comment: Only thing I would disagree on is favoring your device,  I would recommend favoring the most popular device.  This is why the scene editor now defaults to the iPhone 6 size.

Comment: "what your favourite and most desirable target device is", this includes making consideration for the world's view of what constitutes the most popular device. Though if you're targeting iPads, first and foremost, as I do, this is not a consideration.

Comment: no it does not lol, my favorite device is the plus devices,  the popular device is the regular devices,  these are 2 different things here.  iPad gaming really should be modeled differently from iPhone gaming, but for people on a really low budget,  they really should focus on iPhone if they plan on making money off their projects,  unless they plan on making iPad exclusive apps

Comment: Yeah... that's what it says: you must decide, personally, what your favourite **AND** most desirable **TARGET** device is

Comment: but I agree, iPad gaming is something else, and much more fun.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129771/discussion-between-confused-and-knight0fdragon).

Comment: I think that the OP would like suggestions on how to approach this problem, rather than just being told that he needs to decide how to handle it.

Comment: Probably, @SteveIves, but he's still gotta make a decision about which shape (aspect ratio) and which size he's going to use as his primary design and production target. Once that decision is made, all other decisions about how to deal (or not) with other sizes and shapes can be made. There is not a perfect way to design and develop for all screen sizes when things move around and scale on the screen. Everything is a compromise, yet he's (now) coming at this from a myopic view of there being some automagical way of doing positional relativism for both design and development. There isn't.

Comment: His delusion, the dream of a perfect way to deal with all shapes and sizes of screens, is a direct result of the industry wide mantras and nonsense about cross platform development and ease of development.

Comment: I asked a very simple question and wasn't expecting fairy tales in response. The comment section following the question couldn't have been more ridiculous courtesy of @Confused. You can do all your perfect dream talk with a pillow instead rather than making a mess in comment section. The only sensible comment was from Steve Ives who actually took the time to understand what I was trying to know.

Comment: It seems like a simple question, and it can be phrased simply, but the answer is anything but simple because it's not a problem that's easily solved. Despite Apple's best efforts, they haven't solved the problem. Consider this: if it were, as you suggest, simple, then why aren't there any eloquent and simple solutions presented by the far brighter users of SO (which is everyone) than mine? @Alexkiany

Comment: I did not say the answer should be simple or Apple might have given some magic solution on platter. All I wanted to know how capable is scene editor to handle positions of sprites in a scene. It requires positions to be specified in pixels so sprite nodes positioned in the middle of view on 6s plus screen size wouldn't appear in the middle of 6s screen. All I asked is there a way to use scene editor to not face this problem as programatically I specify positions of sprite nodes as self.size.width * 0.7 it maintains nodes relative distances from boundaries regardless of device screen size.

Comment: But it is definitely not a good idea when there are a lot of sprite nodes in a scene especially when they are to placed carefully adjacent to one and another i.e pieces in a puzzle as too much decimal values would be involved that just looks rough though again it can make sure that positions of nodes remain consistent in ratio relative to the boundaries but requires dirty work to calculate too accurate in decimal values to multiply with self.size.width/height. Any suggested solution would be appreciated. I want to create game for both sizes, standard and plus with scene editor if possible.